# GET parameters from URL Yii2

Tags: parameters, yii, get, yii2

I have issue with getting parameters from URL to my Yii2 Controller or Model, to send it in post request via WebService.

Ex. URL : https://example.com/?keyword=test&id=1234

**My Model Save Function code is :**

```
public function save($keyword)
    {
        $httpClient = new Client();
        $data = [
            'civilite'     => $this->civility,
            'nom'          => $this->lastName,
            'prenom'       => $this->firstName,
            'telephone'    => $this->phoneNumber,
            'email'        => $this->emailAddress,
            'operateur'    => $this->operator,
            'tel_domicile' => $this->phone,
            'keyword' => $keyword,
        ];

        $preferences = explode(',', $this->preferences);
        $index = 0;
        foreach ($preferences as $preference) {
            $index++;
            $data['attente' . $index] = $preference;
        }
        LeadLogHelper::log($data);
        $rawResponse = $httpClient->createRequest()
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setUrl(\Yii::$app->params['WebserviceUrl'])
            ->setData($data)
            ->send();
        $response = json_decode($rawResponse->content);

        if (!$response->Statut) {
            Yii::error('An error occurred while saving the data using the webservice', __METHOD__);
            Yii::error($data, __METHOD__);
            Yii::error($response, __METHOD__);
        }
        return $response->Statut == 1 || $response->Message === 'Already exist.';

    }
```

**My Controller Sumbit Action is :**

```
public function actionSubmit()
{
    $leadModel = new LeadModel();

    $data = LeadModelFormHelper::transformDataFormToModel(Yii::$app->request->post());
    $leadModel->setAttributes($data);

    if (!$leadModel->validate()) {
        return $this->sendValidationErrorResponse($leadModel->getErrors());
    }

    $bestOffer = $leadModel->getBestOffer();
    $isSuccessfullySaved = $leadModel->save(Yii::$app->request->get('keyword'));
    if (!$isSuccessfullySaved) {
        $response = $this->asJson(['errors' => ['webservice' => 'Error while saving the lead']]);
        $response->statusCode = 550;
        return $response->send();
    }
    $lastStep = Json::decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../config-offers/offers.json'));

    $isSuccessfullySent = Yii::$app->mailer->compose(
        'offer-summary',
        ArrayHelper::merge($leadModel->getAttributes(), $lastStep['offres'][$bestOffer])
    )
 
        ->setFrom(['noreply@choisirmabox.fr' => 'CHOISIR MA BOX'])
        ->setTo($leadModel->emailAddress)
        ->setSubject('choisirmabox.fr - Votre offre')
        ->send();

    if (!$isSuccessfullySent) {
        Yii::error("Could not send the email", __METHOD__);
    }
return $this->asJson(['offer' => $bestOffer]);
}
```

The keyword have a NULL value, can someone help me please ?!!

Answer (score 1):

[Update]

When I've encountered this issue in the past, I make sure I'm accessing the right params by printing all get params like `\Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams()` or `\Yii::$app->request->get()` just to make sure get params are seen, could be also that the GET parameters were lost if passes thought another action before getting to actionSubmit(). Checking the referer by printing `\Yii::$app->request` could help quickly seeing where is coming before.

Comment: There is no reason why the `GET` params should be inaccessible when the request is send as `POST`. If that was the case even routing won't work for `POST` request because in yii the routes are passed to php scripts in `GET` param.

Comment: @MichalHynčica you're correct, updated the answer to avoid future confusion. I knew there was also the chance of parsing the URL in order to get the params but with Yii no need to do that. Thanks

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help, but why i'm getting this error :[127.0.0.1][-][643po989kc0hhlq10rj8uii2ee][error][yii\web\HttpException:405]
yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: Method Not Allowed. This URL
can only handle the following request methods: POST. in
/var/www/html/dist/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/VerbFilter.php:105
Stack trace:
[internal function]: yii\filters\VerbFilter->beforeAction()
/var/www/html/dist/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(627):
call_user_func()
......

Comment: @Belicoff can you try this [solution](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/method-not-allowed-405-solved/71694/6). In case doesn't work please share your view code as well.

Comment: I have similar kind of issue can you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73581066/6854117)?